# Loop through a list deleting the last element and adding the remaining list to another list

Tags: list, prolog, logic

This is what I've got where this deletes the last element of the list only.

```
delete([_], []).
delete([X|Xs], [X|Last]) :- delete(Xs, Last).
```

The loop should run until the original list is empty an it returns the new list.

It's somewhat similar to subsets.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve upon you definition, avoiding unwanted choice points, by rewriting it as:

```
delete([Head| Tail], List) :-
    delete(Tail, Head, List).

delete([], _, []).
delete([Next| Tail], Previous, [Previous| List]) :-
    delete(Tail, Next, List).
```

Some sample calls:

```
?- delete([1,2,3], L).
L = [1, 2].

?- delete([], L).
false.

?- delete([1], L).
L = [].

?- delete(L, [1,2,3]).
L = [1, 2, 3, _].

 ?- delete(L1, L2).
L1 = [_A],
L2 = [] ? ;
L1 = [_A,_B],
L2 = [_A] ? ;
L1 = [_A,_B,_C],
L2 = [_A,_B] ? ;
L1 = [_A,_B,_C,_D],
L2 = [_A,_B,_C] ? 
...
```

Answer (score 3):

may be :

```
delete_last(In, Out) :-
    append(Out, [_], In).
```

Comment: Nice and compact but shares the same problem with the OP code: it leaves a spurious choice point when called in the mode (+,-).